# How to read this travel itinerary?

Tags: air-travel

```
  2  PR 736 E 22MAR 5 MNLBKK HK1  1455 1745  22MAR  E  PR/OYAHXN               

  3  QV 446 H 22MAR 5 BKKVTE HK1  2025 2125  22MAR  E  QV/RSZBY                

  4  TG2571 W 19APR 5 VTEBKK HK1  1320 1425  19APR  E  TG/JZN28I               

     OPERATED BY THAI SMILE AIRWAYS                                            

  5  PR 737 K 19APR 5 BKKMNL HK1  1755 2225  19APR  E  PR/OYAHXN
```

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, the  PR/OYAHXN  column is not answered in the related question.

Comment: @chx Still, it would make much more sense to post an answer to the other question saying something like "Similar itineraries might contain things like ABC which means blahblah and DEF which means oodleflip." It's not helpful to future users of the site to have to search through multiple different questions of "How do I read this exact itinerary?" hoping to find ones that include all the relevant terms.

Comment: so what does the letters E PR/OYAHXN mean after the date 22MAR?